# Flag counter is missing sporadically

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, flags

I noticed that on both sites where I am a moderator the flag counter is occasionally not showing any flags even when there are flags in the queue. A refresh of the page leads to the correct flag count to be displayed. I noticed this happening when I visited the site for the first time in a few hours, when I was recently active on the site the counter seems to stay accurate.

Comment: Yes, the same thing is with SO's flag queue as well.

Comment: I have the opposite in the mod queue, I have it telling me there are flags, but then shows me nothing.

Comment: @casperOne I see that too, I know exactly which post the phantom flag is on and can see it unresolved in the post history, but it doesn't show in the flag list

Comment: May or may not be the same bug: [Do not cache the flag indicator for moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186965/do-not-cache-the-flag-indicator-for-moderators)

Comment: seems hard to track down, do you have repro steps?

Comment: @Sklivvz It happens pretty consistently if I haven't been to the site in a while. On the first page load there are no flags, and when I reload the page they appear.