# Do not cache the flag indicator for moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, top-bar, caching

Since the flagging and closing changes back in June, I get the impression that the flag indicator is now cached (or more properly speaking buffered). I've observed several times on both [FR](https://french.stackexchange.com/) and [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) that I visit a page, which shows no flag indicator, then I visit some other page, which shows an hours-old flag.

When I dismiss a flag and immediately reload the front page, the flag indicator does go away, so it seems that the caching is only in one direction, or maybe there's an additional check to avoid displaying 0.

As a moderator, I sometimes load a page while I'm doing other things with my computer, just to check if there are any flags. For this I really need to have up-to-date flag information.

Please do not cache the flag indicator (at least outside SO, where the difference between 400 pending flags and 450 pending flags isn't so important), or at least, do not buffer the transition from 0 to nonzero. If there's a flag, make sure that the next page load by a moderator shows that there is a flag.

*Note that this is a months-old bug, that the new top bar did not cause but did not fix either.*

Comment: I've observed the same thing, and it is rather annoying: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186040/flag-counter-is-missing-sporadically

Comment: I've observed flag queue count weirdness as well, even after the count [discrepancy with own-flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186650/145951) got resolved. I haven't been able to pin it down, but this sounds like the same thing.

Comment: @MadScientist Probably the same bug, but slightly different observations. I've seen this: load home page → no flag counter. Shift-reload → still no counter. Visit a question → counter appears. Reload the home page → counter is now visible.

Comment: Not caching is not the correct answer here, it's properly resetting the cache when it changes - that not happening is a bug.  Not caching a lookup that changes relatively rarely is just not smart at our scale, *always* cache a repeated result, just clear it when it should change...that appears to be missing in some case we'll track down here.

Comment: @NickCraver Any update? It's annoying and embarassing to load the home page, see that all is good, reload the home page an hour later and see that some flags (spam and custom) have been sitting overnight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was finally fixed a while ago.