# Moderator flags incorrectly displayed

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

As you can see from this screenshot, the flag page indicates I have one flag to deal with, but the tab title says zero flags, and the page is empty of flags.

Just a caching/race condition that will clear up soon?

[image]

(and yes, when I took the screenshot it looked like the page was updating - it didn't change)

Comment: Has come up before but I can't seem to find it any longer - yeah, it's caching.

Comment: Could it be a flag against a post of yours? I can't remember if we get to handle them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just caching, and only really noticeable on sites where there's only a few (less than page of) flags pending at any given time, you'll almost never notice this on Stack Overflow, or other sites that get a few flags every few minutes.

It'll normalize rather quickly.

Comment: It's more annoying [in the other direction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186965/do-not-cache-the-flag-indicator-for-moderators), where I load a site's home page, see that all is good (no flags), and wander off to other sites, whereas there was a flag which is now staying behind unnoticed.